# Having losetup read the partition table

Tags: linux

For the purpose of learning, I wanted to create a mini-replica of my hard disk:

```
$ lsblk

NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                     8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0   244M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                  8:3    0 930.8G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt        254:0    0 930.8G  0 crypt 
    ├─host--vg-root   254:1    0    25G  0 lvm   /
    ├─host--vg-var    254:2    0   2.8G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─host--vg-swap_1 254:3    0  11.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─host--vg-tmp    254:4    0   380M  0 lvm   /tmp
    └─host--vg-home   254:5    0   890G  0 lvm   /home
```

In my particular case, setting up a new device so it looks like my hard disk requires familiarity with many things, creating partitions, creating LUKS devices, opening them, creating LVM volumes etc, so I regard this as a worthy exercise, at least for someone who is new to Linux.

So I first needed a new device to play with, without messing up anything else:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=loopfile bs=1M count=1024
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop1 loopfile
```

(using `loop1` rather than `loop0` which is already taken for some other purpose, also `zero` good enough for this exercise so ignoring `urandom`).

My first objective was to mimic the partitions `sda1/sda2/sda3`

```
$ sudo blkid

/dev/sda1: UUID="08FC-EA23" TYPE="vfat" ...
/dev/sda2: UUID="30b5d595-4986-4f75-962a-7e1f5f03ed4a" TYPE="ext2" ...
/dev/sda3: UUID="a84cc598-9316-48b9-94a9-bb4885e45e9c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" ...

$ sudo parted /dev/loop1
```

So I went and created three 'primary' partitions (using 'fat32' for the first one and 'ext2' for other two, not too sure why just guessing) with all sizes reduced by a factor of 1000:

```
(parted) print

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      512B    1000kB  1000kB  primary  fat32        lba
2      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB  primary  ext2         lba
3      2097kB  1074MB  1072MB  primary  ext2         lba
```

and I then formatted the three devices in line with the previous `blkid` report:

```
sudo mkfs -t vfat /dev/loop1p1
sudo mkfs -t ext2 /dev/loop1p2
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/loop1p3
```

So at this point, my parted `print` report looks good as well as lsblk and blkid:

```
$ lsblk

loop1                   7:1    0     1G  0 loop  
├─loop1p1             259:0    0 976.5K  0 loop  
├─loop1p2             259:1    0     1M  0 loop  
└─loop1p3             259:2    0  1022M  0 loop

$ sudo blkid

/dev/loop1p1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="1CD8-2CA5" TYPE="vfat" ...
/dev/loop1p2: UUID="6532dba9-3101-488e-a6d1-e5e1ef4943f7" TYPE="ext2" ...
/dev/loop1p3: UUID="a0e96a54-6d6a-49c8-80fd-03217b25062f" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" ...
/dev/loop1: PTUUID="1de285f7" PTTYPE="dos"
```

So I thought I was on the right track. I also thought that my file `loopfile` which underlies my loop device would contain of the necessary metadata so I do not need to worry about rebooting. As I am only playing with devices (not mounting them) I assumed there is no need for any `/etc/fstab` setup...

The issue I have is that when I reboot, some of the set up seems to be lost. After re-creating the loop device from `loopfile`, the `parted` `print` report still shows me the partitions (albeit with lost information on `type`), but these partitions no longer appear on the `lsblk` or the `blkid` reports. I was wondering if there was a way of making my set up persistant. I am on Debian 8, in case this matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `losetup -P /dev/loop1 loopfile`. What this does is tell the kernel to perform a partition table scan of the newly added file.

Comment: perfect thank you !! :)